# GIPO and event ValueChanged in class library

Tags: c#, events, gpio

I'm trying to make a manager in my Common class library project (netstandard) and I'm stuck with my **gpio.ValueChanged**:

```
this.gpioPin.ValueChanged += this.PinIn_ValueChanged;

private void PinIn_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
}
```

I got this error in **PinIn_ValueChanged**:

> Argument type 'method group' is not assignable to parameter type 'Windows.Foundation.TypeEventHandler`2'

Do I really have to reference Windows Foundation in my project?

[GPIO Value_changed event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.gpio.gpiopin.valuechanged)

[Example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/IoT-GPIO/cs/Scenario2_Listen.xaml.cs)

Thank you

EDIT (more infos): I need to reference my library project from my UWP and ASP.NET (.NET CORE 3.0) projects. And in my Common Library I need to use Gpio.ValueChanged from UWP ref.

After referenced Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, I got this error in ValueChanged:

> CS1545 C# Property, indexer, or event is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods GpioPin.add_ValueChanged(TypedEventHandler)' or 'GpioPin.remove_ValueChanged(EventRegistrationToken)'

Comment: Are you sure that's the error? Or did you misspell the type in the error?

Comment: @RonBeyer No no, even if i reference "Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract" i got this error:  'Event GpioPin.ValueChanged is not supported by language; try to call the accessor methods directly 'GpioPin.add_ValueChanged...."

Comment: Is this an IOT core project? You say net standard, do you have the IOT extensions SDK installed?

Comment: I created uwp project, then ASP.net project, finaly class library in .netstandard. i edited my post (check EDIT)